# How to access CA certificates when building derivation

Tags: nix

I want to automatically add CA certificates to Java keystore when running `nix-shell`. Before the following script worked:

```hs
with import <nixpkgs> {
  config.allowUnfree = true;
  config.oraclejdk.accept_license = true;
};

let dependencies = rec {
  _oraclejdk8 = stdenv.lib.overrideDerivation pkgs.oraclejdk8 (attrs : {
    installPhase = ''
      ${attrs.installPhase}

      pems_dir=pems
      mkdir "$pems_dir"

      echo "split bundled ca-certificates into separate files 'cert.N.pem'\
                and add them to default keystore"

      keytool=$out/bin/keytool
      keystore=$jrePath/lib/security/cacerts

      pushd "$pems_dir"
      awk 'BEGIN {c=0;doPrint=0;} /END CERT/ {print > "cert." c ".pem";doPrint=0;} /BEGIN CERT/{c++;doPrint=1;} { if(doPrint == 1) {print > "cert." c ".pem"} }' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

      # import certificates
      for f in `ls cert.*.pem`; do
        alias=`basename $f`
        $keytool -import -trustcacerts -noprompt -keystore "$keystore" -alias "$alias" -file "$f" -storepass changeit;
      done
      popd

    '';
  });

};
in with dependencies;
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "env";
  buildInputs = [ _oraclejdk8 ];
}
```

But now it fails with the following error:

```
/nix/store/9fx2jfmks2zhvv2kmqgl6rg0fbkc3da0-stdenv-linux/setup: line 1391: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt: No such file or directory
```

It looks like now it is not possible to access any existing files. But actually this file is just a link to store:

```
$ readlink -f /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
/nix/store/w3vw4q9z7s0wig6ng4nv62af1917ynrm-ca-certificates.crt
```

How can I access this file in my script?

Answer (score 3):

Nix is a hermetic build system, meaning that all inputs must be declared so they can all be tracked.
You could pull in Nixpkgs' set of certificate authority certificates, being `pkgs.cacert`:

```
  # CAREFUL, read on!
  awk 'BEGIN {c=0;doPrint=0;} /END CERT/ {print > "cert." c ".pem";doPrint=0;} /BEGIN CERT/{c++;doPrint=1;} { if(doPrint == 1) {print > "cert." c ".pem"} }' < ${cacert}/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

However, be careful when pinning cryptographic configuration, because when it changes you need it to be updated everywhere. Suppose you want to run a 2-year old version of your software, do you want to run it with 2-year old certificates or the certificates from the environment?

Another problem is where are these certificates supposed to be written to? Keytool writes to the home directory by default, which is the non-existent one in the build sandbox.

It seems like the right solution in your case is not adding the certificates inside the sandbox, but returning a script that will do it in the context where it makes sense to do so. When and where is up to you, but please make sure you get those certificates from a good source. If you can assume your deployments are always done with a sufficiently up to date Nixpkgs, you can go with that. Otherwise, you're probably better off with the ones already on the system in `/etc`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The goal actually is to take certificates from the current configuration (`/etc`) because it contains some additional certificates for out man-in-the-middle proxy. It means that `pkgs.cacert` cannot help. I wonder if it is possible to access current NixOS configuration from my script?

Comment: If you want to do it immutably in a derivation, you could concatenate your mitm cert to the file in `pkgs.cacert`. If you want to take it from the evaluating host, use `${/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt}`. If you want to do it at runtime, use `pkgs.writeScript` or possibly `shellHook`.

Comment: I have tried this `${/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt}` - it is expanded to a path in store, but the problem is that this path is actually another symbolic link which points to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` which in turn points to a correct derivation in store. But since `/etc` is not accessible when script is executed this approach doesn't work. It looks like I need to add a dependency on the correct derivation manually, but I don't know how. Can you advice?

Comment: You could try `builtins.toFile "ca-bundle.crt" (builtins.readFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt)`. I really doubt that this is a maintainable approach though. Is this supposed to be a quick hack for yourself or is this going to be deployed?

Comment: I agree, it doesn't look like nice approach. But in general why the one cannot take something from the host configuration when building derivation. I spent some time adding ca-certs to NixOS configuration and I don't want to spend more time adding it to every java application I use. From my point of view there should be some natural way for inheriting host configuration by derivations built on it. But I probably don't understand some fundamental idea behind Nix :)

Comment: I'd say the fundamental idea is you can have a pure function from files to 'immutable infrastructure'. So every time you want to switch to new immutable infrastructure you have to change some file. Put those files in git and you have a predictable system, except for behavior at runtime. So should certificates be part of the input or part of the runtime behavior? TBH I can't judge that without more details, so let's leave it at that. Perhaps those java applications should all read from the same key store, just like unix apps read /etc/ssl?